# Mac OSX ld report 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range error for Absolute symbol

Tags: macos, linker

I'm trying to combine `objcopy` with clang toolchain.
Because `objcopy` of binutils 2.25 generates broken Mach-O object file, I edit generated object file using [my shell script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a87824d6c5430008e87).

```
$ objcopy-comp.sh -I binary -O mach-o-x86-64 test test.o
$ nm test.o
000000000000000b D _binary_test_end
000000000000000b A _binary_test_size
0000000000000000 D _binary_test_start
```

However, link against a C code fails with this error message.

```
$ clang main.c test.o
ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (-4294971146 max is +/-4GB): 
  from _main (0x100000EA0) to _binary_test_size (0x0000000B) 
  in '_main' from main.o for architecture x86_64
```

(Newlines are inserted for readbility)

Here is main.c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern const unsigned char binary_test_start[];
extern const unsigned char binary_test_end[];
extern const unsigned char binary_test_size[];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  size_t len = binary_test_end - binary_test_start;
  char *data = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
  memcpy(data, binary_test_start, len);
  data[len] = 0;
  printf("%s %ld %d\n", data, len, (int)binary_test_size);
  return 0;
}
```

[According to nlist document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/#//apple_ref/c/tag/nlist),

> N_ABS (0x2)—The symbol is absolute. The linker does not change the value of an absolute symbol.

but the error message suggests that linker does try to change the value.

How to protect Absolute value from linker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Mach-O`ABI utilizes relative addressing with `x86_64`. The compiler interprets the address you've used as `32-bit` which is out range, nor will it be absolute. Try compiling your code as `i386` only and you might have a better chance of success.

Specifically how you're changing the symbol types is unknown since you haven't shown the commands you've used with `objcopy`.

Comment: Thanks, i386 solved the problem, but is this the only solution? I uploaded the script used and fixed arguments of `objcopy`. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: There are other solutions perhaps; you could possibly use `GOTPCREL` addressing, or just modify the objcopy source code and make your modifications there then compile it.

Comment: I checked `GOTPCREL`, and understood the possibility, but it is a bit hard for me to complete implementation now. I will try sometime. Thank you for advice.